# How to deny the Users at Zonejoin level [Every user is entering into Zone even authentication fails]

Tags: smartfoxserver

Recently I am facing a problem that every user (valid/invalid) is joining into the room even I throw the SFSException at ZonejinRequest..
So can anyone explain how to authenticate / stop the invalid users at Zonejoin level with sample snippet. (and also how to remove the joined user from zone if possible)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got the Bug and it solved,
Here my bug is I put the code like this

```
try {
   if (getApi().checkSecurePassword((ISession)event.getParameter(SFSEventParam.SESSION),plainpwd,pwd)) {
       trace("welcome");
   } else {
       SFSErrorData errData = new SFSErrorData(SFSErrorCode.LOGIN_BAD_PASSWORD);
       errData.addParameter(username);
       throw new SFSLoginException(" Password mismatched ", errData);
   }
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

so My Exception block it self catching that SFSLoginException.. so I removed outer try/catch now working fine.